# how to deploy helm chart from gitlab to eks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

I created a kubernetes cluster and linked it with eks.

I created also an helm chart and .gitla-ci.yml.
I want to add a new step to deploy my app using helm to the cluster, but I don't find a recent tutorial. All tutorials use gitlab-auto devops.

The image is hosted on gitlab.

How could I do to achieve this task ?

```
image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind

variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: test
    USER_GITLAB: kosted
    APP_NAME: mebooks
    REPO: gara-mebooks
    MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
    MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"


stages:
    - deploy



k8s-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.1.2
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    # Read certificate stored in $KUBE_CA_PEM variable and save it in a new file
    - echo $KUBE_URL
    - kubectl config set-cluster gara-eks-cluster --server="$KUBE_URL" --certificate-authority="$KUBE_CA_PEM"
    - kubectl get pods
```

In the gitlab console I got

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
>   specify the right host or port? Running after_script 00:01 Uploading
>   artifacts for failed job 00:02 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: You failed to specify what you've already tried that didn't work for you, above and beyond the fact that you left off why the Auto DevOps process provided by Gitlab doesn't work for you, given that you went to the trouble of connecting your EKS cluster to it

Comment: @mdaniel I updated the code with a simple example and more details

Answer (score 2):

1 - Create arn role or user on IAM from your aws console
2 - connect to your bastion and add the arn role/user in the ConfigMap aws-auth
 you can follow this to understand how it works (you are not the creator of the cluster paragraph) : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/
3- In your gitlab ci you just have to add this if it is a user you have created :

```
k8s-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: you need an image with aws + kubectl + helm
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - aws --version
    - aws --profile default configure set aws_access_key_id "your access id"
    - aws --profile default configure set aws_secret_access_key "your secret"
    - helm version
    - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name NAME-OF-YOUR-CLUSTER --region eu-west-3
    - helm upgrade init
    - helm upgrade --install my-chart ./my-chart-folder
```

If you created a role note a user, you have just to do:

```
   k8s-deploy:
      stage: deploy
      image: you need an image with aws + kubectl + helm
      only:
        - develop
      script:
        - aws --version
        - helm version
        - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name NAME-OF-YOUR-CLUSTER --region eu-west-3 -arn
        - helm upgrade init
        - helm upgrade --install my-chart ./my-chart-folder
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I am adding my method, which is generic and can be used in any K8S environment without AWS CLI.

First, you need to convert your Kube Config to a base64 string:

```
cat ~/.kube/config | base64
```

Add the result string as a variable to your CI/CD pipeline settings of the project/group. In my example I used `kube_config`. [Read more on how to add variables here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project)

Here is my CI YAML file:

```
stages:
  # - build
  # - test
  - deploy

variables:
  KUBEFOLDER: /root/.kube
  KUBECONFIG: $KUBEFOLDER/config


k8s-deploy-job: 
  stage: deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.5.0
  before_script:
    - mkdir ${KUBEFOLDER}
    - echo ${kube_config} | base64 -d > ${KUBECONFIG}
    - helm version
    - helm repo update
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - kubectl get pods
    #- helm upgrade --install my-chart ./my-chart-folder
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Inspired by:
https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/21/how-to-create-ci-cd-pipeline-with-autodeploy-to-kubernetes-using-gitlab-and-helm/